# Versioning workflow with ftp-servers, coding on mac

Tags: macos, version-control, ftp, shared-hosting

I am searching since at least 29 years ;-) but I don't find anything, that would match my understanding of a good workflow.

Isn't there any tool, to do some versioning with shared-hosting ftp-servers for web-development on a mac?

This is my case: I am php-coder, just have written a bigger application with Symfony. now, as the 1.0 is final and released, I have setup a dev release, where I can test and develop - but each time I want to publish a new release, I have to look for all files, that changed since the last update and upload them by hand or just update everything (7000+files...).

There MUST be anyone who had this problem and wrote a versioning tool for mac or a versioning and deployment plugin for eclipse or whatever for testing AND publishing on different ftp-servers (and publishing cannot be github or whatever, because its all about shared-hosting) - does anyone know one?

Thanks so much!

Comment: If I remember right, Git versioning system have support for mac

Comment: SourceAnywhere Hosted can do that. It has Java Client for Mac. The Web Deployment feature is also available for you to deploy the files/projects to your ftp site.

Comment: @GokhanOzturk I cant get git to gimme 2 local copies, track changes and upload everything via ftp - I tried several git guis...

Comment: @Windy Looks not too bad, but its not a tool, its an online-service. I need (or want) a tool to achieve this. But thanks! :-) 
EDIT: just have seen the Java-Client - but its not free. I'd prefer a one-time fee or a free solution.

Comment: @mvmoay If you are looking for a standalone tool instead of a hosting service, you can try SourceAnywhere Standalone. It shares the same set of features with the hosted edition. The product is one user free. FYI, for SourceAnywhere Hosted Free Plan, the java client is free. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found myself beginning to use bitbucket. Didn't like git, so I use mercurial for now. Works fine, as I can submit everything once I finished an update and sync changed files to the production environment.

SVN is quite cool... :-)

Thanks for your thoughts!

### UPDATE

Some months later, i found http://www.gitlabhq.com/ - exactly what i was searching for. Didn't really have the time to use it, but seems to fit the needs!

Comment: BTW - GitlabHQ isn't deploy system per se. You can really to use *any SCM, supported by OSX*, and deploys changes by script (manually started) or specially crafted post-commit hook (for systems, which have concept of hooks)

Answer (score 0):

If you'll use (for example) Subversion (svn-client **exist** in OSX) you can use any [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063724/960558) bash-scripts for automating deploy (for *any* transfer-protocol really) of files, changed between revisions (OLD-RELEASE and NEW-RELEASE in your case) with (possibly) smallest adaptations or Ryby-script, which export range from a box.

Uploading tree by FTP in unattended way is a task for second tool - [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/), [ncftpput](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html) namely