# How to overwrite several multi-level(different hierarchy) files from a local version to an online version via FTP

Tags: svn, version-control, ftp

I just changed a lot of files in several different directories locally (then pushed the changes to Subversion, but this does not change the live version, just the repository).   Now I have to update those files via FTP, but they are all different hierarchy levels.

How do I do that?   Only way I know how to is to take my entire local version and replace the online version, but that could take some time, and its a live site...

Looking for a faster way...? Something along the lines of I can see the files that were changed in the commit, and take those and upload it to the FTP site, not having to worry about the different hierarchy levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [svn export changed files per revision](http://thomasfischer.biz/?p=203) - Bash, 1 revision
- [ExportRevs](http://kurakin.info/files/exportrevs.zip) - Ruby, revision range
- [Subversion Command Line Script to export changed files](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/subversion-export-changed-files-cli/) - Bash, not tested

---

- [Exporting only changed files in TortoiseSVN between versions](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/tortoisesvn-exporting-changed-files/) - GUI, Win-only, range