# How can I copy Incremental files from SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can i copy the physical files modified/added in between two revisions in SVN. Suppose I have modified 10 files as in between revision 2 and 4, I need those 10 files alone in some folders outside svn.

Comment: *What* physical files? SVN tracks *changes* (differences); it doesn't store a complete copy of every file in every state.

Comment: A more complete description what you are trying to do may be in order, right now the question is open to more interpretations, OTOH I already came up with 3, all requiring wildly different solutions...

Comment: Please find the updated question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to overwrite several multi-level(different hierarchy) files from a local version to an online version via FTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058444/how-to-overwrite-several-multi-leveldifferent-hierarchy-files-from-a-local-ver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you question can be translated into something like this:

"How to export files, affected in *some-revisions-range*, saving original tree in exported results"

then read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063724/960558) in topic "How to overwrite several multi-level(different hierarchy) files from a local version to an online version via FTP" (why you didn't try search at least here before asking)"

- for CLI-clients (and sometimes for server-side tools) - 3 URLs from beginning
- for TortoiseSVN - latest link

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking is how to make sure a working copy has the latest version of all the files, you want to use the update command.

From the top directory of the working copy, run the command: `svn update`

You might also want to look at `svn help update` for the full range of update options.