# Apply TortoiseSVN patch without SVN client

Tags: svn, patch

I am currently working on a patch for an open-source program (not authored by me) used by other people who are not very computer literate. I keep my changes stored in a personal SVN and would like to distribute them in a patch to these "other people". Normally, if they are programmers, I could've just given them an SVN patch file and then could just merge the changes, but again, that's out of question.

A possible solution would be to bundle all the changed files together (with preserved hierarchy) and tell the others to unpack and overwrite, but it can be a bit annoying to keep track of which files were changed and which files weren't as well as the need to write a script for that.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SVN is not for distributing software or pathes to end-users. You should use some installer.

Inno Setup from JRSoftware is very powerful tool for creating installers.

You can use some wizard to pre-configure your installer, then customize it by changing script that generates exe file.

[Here you can download IS (Inno Setup)](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php)

If you are not familiar with tools like this - you should get "QuickStart Pack" version.

Answer (score 0):

> it can be a bit annoying to keep track of which files were changed and which files weren't

Not for you.

If you know, which revision in your repo is "vanilla code" (of original program), you can

- get tree of only changed files in revrange (rev:HEAD)
- tag your current HEAD as `<ANYLABEL>`
- next time for producing tree use ANYLABEL:HEAD range and repeat from p.2

> the need to write a script for that

[Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063724/960558) and method for TortoiseSVN for exporting range of revisions